# blender to substance painter help (overlapping UVs)

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-painting

im new to both blender and substance painter. This will be my first texturing exersize so i wouldnt be surprised if I have missed something simple.
but basically my model is comprised of 5 different components. as you can see in the first screenshot I have the main part of the shuttle, the door, the rockets on the back ect. I have also colour Id'd many parts of the model as to easily seperate materials in substance painter.[image]
each component of the model is UV unwrapped individually.
however my issue is that when i export my model as an FBX and import it to substance painter, all of the UV maps get combined with one another.
as you can see in the below screenshots, this causes an immediate problem. when i paint on one component of the model, my texture gets carried onto another component of the model. 
[image]
[image]

if anyone could help find a solution to this, tell me some way to stop these components from overlapping on the UV it would be greatly appreciated.

-James

Comment: In order to stop UV islands from overlapping you should place them in UV space so that they don't overlap. Either by packing (Ctrl+P in UV editor window with islands selected) or by manually moving and arranging them or by reunwrapping.

Comment: Just add different materials for every part.